# why myTabSelectedListener not triggered if the initial tab selection is index 0?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

so I want my tab programatically switch based on certain condition, so I have this code on my onResume

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // programatically set tab position based on certain condition
        if (someConditionHere == 0) {
          tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.select()
        } else if (someConditionHere == 1) {
          tabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.select()
        }



    }
```

and then I have listener to handle when the user select a tab on my tab layout like this

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {


            if  (tab?.position == 0) {
                performActionA()
            } else if (tab?.position == 1) {
                performActionB()
            }



        }

        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

        }


    })

}
```

when the first time onResume is triggered and `someConditionHere == 1` , then `onTabSelected` will be called to trigger `performActionB()`

but unfortunately, when `someConditionHere == 0` in the beginning, then `onTabSelected` will NOT be called so `performActionA()` will NOT be triggered at the first time. I suspect the tab layout default is on index 0 , so when the condition is also in index tab 0, then the `addOnTabListener` will not be triggered

how to fix this ? I want my `performActionA()` is get called from the beginning when `someConditionHere == 0`. if hard code `performActionA()` in `onResume()` it will be called twice unfortunately

java/kotlin is okay

Comment: Have you tried using `onTabReselected`? Because it means that the tab has already been selected and has been selected again. Therefore, you would also need to check the tab position and perform the action again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` there is a method called `onTabReselected`, as mentioned in my comment, its purpose is for a tab that has already been selected and has been selected again.

Therefore, you would want to replace its content with the content of `onTabSelected`.

So, it would be better if you create a function so you don't have to repeat the code.

```
fun performNecessaryAction(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    if  (tab?.position == 0) {
        performActionA()
    } else if (tab?.position == 1) {
        performActionB()
    }
}
```

And the listener would look like the following...

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        performNecessaryAction(tab)
    }

    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        performNecessaryAction(tab)
    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

    }
})
```